# Show Output when Date in DatagridView matches today's Date

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a datagridview named `DGVPatient` which several columns one of them is `Entry Date`. Another control TextBox named `TxtEntry`.

I want the program to show a warning message and lock down all controls (buttons, checkboxes, textboxes etc.) when the value of the selected patient (row) `DGVPatient.Column["Entry Date"].Cells[7].Value.ToString()` == `DateTime.Today.Date`.

So, how could I extract, convert, add, and store the sum of `Convert.ToInt32(DGVPatientTxtEntry.SelectedRow[7].Cell.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(TxtEnter.Text)`? I was thinking about creating a hidden column called Patient Renewal to store the reult and compare it to `DateTime.Today.Date`

[image]

Comment: What is the *actual* type of that Entry Date  column? You should never compare string representations of data in general and Dates in particular. These are subject to change due to regional settings. If the database you are working with actually stores dates as strings, that's an awful desing and should be worked around only if there is no other way around it.

Comment: The actual datatype of Entry Date is DateTime and I am using SQL server management studio. Any ideas how to work this around? Thanks in previous

Comment: If the underlying data source data for the column in the grid is of a type `DateTime`… then, why not compare the dates directly… something like… `if (((DateTime)dr[“dateCol"]).Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date)) { ...`

Comment: That is the solution for another problem, kindly re-read my question. I want to show a wsrning message to the physician saying:"patient renewal required" when the sum of Entry date and Esitimated stay equals datetime.today.date... Let's say a patients enters hospital today on 25/9/2021 and he is estimated to stay for 2 days that makes the potential patient discharge date on 27/9/2021, after 2 working days and when the computer's clock is actually 27/9/2021 after user login and all. Upon clicking a row in DGVPatient, the doctor will be reminded to write down a patient renewal report.

Comment: Couldn’t you just add two days to the enter date? Something like… `var endDate = EnterDate.AddDays(2)`…?

Comment: Where is the like button? I can use that approach and store the sum of the entry date and estimated stay in am estimated leave or renewal date columns . then compare them and go on. thank you mate. kindly post your last command as an answer for my to accept it as an answer <3